# Умножение длинных чисел

Tags: c++

Интересует не столько решение, сколько причина по которой программа выводит неверный результат

```
uint64_t temp = 15482202590115775738;
uint64_t temp2 = 2* temp;
std::cout<< temp2;
```

Результат выводится неверно. (Запускаю на 64х разрядном компиляторе)

Comment: Окей, написал код, увидел, что UINT_MAX меньше, чем необходимый размер, теперь интересует решение

Comment: А при чем здесь UINT_MAX?

Comment: @AnT а что не так? переполнение получается при умножение, поэтому и UINT_MAX, ниже вы расписали более подробно то, что написал я

Comment: Здесь роль играет `UINT64_MAX`, а не `UINT_MAX`. `UINT_MAX` здесь вообще ни при чем.

Comment: @AnT а понял, описался

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Запустил. Получил `12517661106521999860`.

И что значит "неверный результат"? А какой результат вы ожидали?

В языках С и С++ беззнаковый тип `uint64_t` реализует арифметику по модулю 2<sup>64</sup> = `18446744073709551616` = `UINT64_MAX + 1`.

Математически `15482202590115775738 * 2` дает `30964405180231551476`, что превышает 2<sup>64</sup> и по модулю 2<sup>64</sup> равно `12517661106521999860`.

Именно это число и выводит ваша программа. Все правильно.

---

Однако отдельно стоить заметить, что бессуффиксные целые литералы в С и С++ всегда имеют *знаковый* тип. И если литерал не помещается в самый большой знаковый тип `long long` и компилятор не хочет использовать какой-нибудь расширенный тип, то программа является некорректной (см. комментарий @jfs). На вашей платформе, я подозреваю, тип `long long` является 64-битным. Тогда правильно: `15482202590115775738u`

Comment: да, с этим разобрался, кроме как написать свой класс и хранить число, например, в векторе вариантов нет?

Comment: @John стандартных средств пока что нет. Есть Boost.Multiprecision, gmp и другие библиотеки

Comment: @John: Зависит от компилятора. Реализации могут предоставлять свои собственные, более широкие типы. GCC, например, поддерживает `__int128` (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc64d500baf25f05). А иначе - да, класс. Свой или готовый.

Comment: интересно, что hex,oct,bin константы могут быть unsigned  (и также обычные константы до Си(99)). Константы также могут иметь расширенный тип такой как `__int128` (если компилятор поддерживает). Компилятор обязан диагностику выдать для слишком большой константы ("program is ill-formed"). http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

Comment: @jfs: Да, верно. У меня откуда-то в голове болталось "поведение не определено". Возможно, из С, где явного утверждения ошибочности программы нет. А в С++ действительно явно сказано - программа ill-formed. Хотя виду, что и С11 явно говорит, что в такой ситуации константа "has no type", и при этом требует "Each constant shall have a type". Тогда и в С - программа ошибочна.

Answer (score 3):

Как-то мне тоже понадобилась длинная арифметика. Но использовать GMP было нельзя, так как длинная арифметика нужна была для микроконтроллеров без операционной системы и кучи. Пришлось написать свою библиотеку С++ шаблонов для работы с длинными целыми числами, которая не использует кучу. Вот ссылка:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/muntl/?source=frontpage&position=6

Там в архиве есть и описание на русском языке.